# SVG, jQuery and Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, internet-explorer-9

I am trying to use jQuery with inline SVG on Internet Explorer 9. It's something very basic, but I can't seem to get it to work. All I would like to do is use jQuery to "alert" when I click on a rectangle. Here below is the code I've tried:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<script type="text/ecmascript" xlink:href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" />
<script type="text/ecmascript"><![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#bot").click(function (){
            alert("clicked");
        });
    });
]]></script>

<rect x="10" y="10" height="300" width="300" style="fill: #000000" id="bot" />

</svg>

<!--
<script type="text/javascript" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" />
<script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#bot").click(function (){
        alert("clicked");
    });
});
]]></script>
-->
```

I can click as much as I want on the rectangle, but nothing happens. Does anybody know why and how to fix it in Internet Explorer 9 (works fine in Firefox) using only plain jQuery and no other libraries?

As you can see I've tried putting the JS part both inside and outside the SVG tag to see if that had any effect. It did not!

Comment: Just to note, the example above doesn't work in Chrome 23 either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `<script/>`, use `<script></script>`.

Working example (tested in IE9 and Chrome 23):

http://jsfiddle.net/LrKbS/6/

According to the SVG spec, using `<script/>` is correct, but there was [a bug](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=17995) (recently fixed) in the HTML5 spec with foreign content handling and script end tag processing.

Comment: brilliant works perfectly. no idea why, but it'll only work if i add an svg dtd at the top of the doc. this is not required by firefox